# How to find the max of 2 vectors element-wise?

Tags: r

```
a <- c(-1, 0, 2, 3)
b <- c(0, 2, 9, -3)
```

I have 2 vectors here of equal length. I want to find the value that is the maximum of the 2 vectors element-wise. That is, I want to compare the first element of `a` and `b` and find the bigger value, then compare the second, third, etc. I want the final vector to be `0, 2, 9, 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax` in `base R`

```
pmax(a, b, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0 2 9 3
```